xv6 PLIC initialize Hart
In xv6 memlayout.h: line 20:
// qemu puts UART registers here in physical memory.
#define UART0 0x10000000L
#define UART0_IRQ 10

// virtio mmio interface
#define VIRTIO0 0x10001000
#define VIRTIO0_IRQ 1

// qemu puts platform-level interrupt controller (PLIC) here.
#define PLIC 0x0c000000L
#define PLIC_PRIORITY (PLIC + 0x0)
#define PLIC_PENDING (PLIC + 0x1000)
#define PLIC_SENABLE(hart) (PLIC + 0x2080 + (hart)*0x100)
#define PLIC_SPRIORITY(hart) (PLIC + 0x201000 + (hart)*0x2000)
#define PLIC_SCLAIM(hart) (PLIC + 0x201004 + (hart)*0x2000)

...

void
plicinithart(void)
{
  int hart = cpuid();
  
  // set enable bits for this hart's S-mode
  // for the uart and virtio disk.
  *(uint32*)PLIC_SENABLE(hart) = (1 << UART0_IRQ) | (1 << VIRTIO0_IRQ);

  // set this hart's S-mode priority threshold to 0.
  *(uint32*)PLIC_SPRIORITY(hart) = 0;
}

I want to know why #define PLIC_SENABLE(hart) (PLIC + 0x2080 + (hart)*0x100) begins with PLIC + 0x2080?
I have checked SiFive FU540-C000 Manual: v1p0 and on page 61, it said that PLIC + 0x2080 is "Start Hart 1 M-Mode interrupt enables", rather than "Start Hart 0 S-Mode interrupt enables".

These bits would enable M-mode interrupts. I am not familiar with this OS architecture, but I presume the interrupts are handled in machine mode.

Note, that the PLIC has two "outputs" connected to two distinct core "pins", which are Machine External interrupt and Supervisor External interrupt pins. So enabling this register will route the interrupts to the former.

@EugeneSh. That makes sense. Thank you!
